# How to Flip Pages in React Native ScrollView/Flatlist

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I want to achieve the flipping transition between pages in ScrollView, just like it's done in iBooks reader. I looked at [the docs for ScrollView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollenabled) but didn't see how it can be achieved. Is this something that's achievable? How? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with **Animations** in React Native, You can read more about in the [React native Animation docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations).
You can achieve transition, rotation as you need it.

Below link contains an example for ScrollView with Animation.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/animations#scrollview-with-animated-event-example